# User is set to AnonymousUser after a user_logged_in signal is received in Django with all-auth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have spent all day trying to figure out why after user user signedup with django all-auth then is redirect to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL but with AnonymousUser instead user have just signed up.

This is my all-auth settings:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = "Focoosin"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE = False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = True
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 3
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
```

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
   SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False

I see the that the following are fired after user signedup

user_signed_up

```
@receiver(user_signed_up, dispatch_uid="some.unique.id")
def user_signed_up_(request, user, **kwargs):
    print request.user
```

Here I see the request.user as AnonymousUser
user_logged_in:

```
@receiver(user_logged_in, dispatch_uid="some.unique.string")
def user_logged_in_(request, user, **kwargs):
    print request.user
```

Here I see request.user as ""

Would be great get some ideas about what could be happening or the reason of it.

Comment: Hey any updates on this problem

Answer (score 1):

That is why a User instance is also passed in as a parameter. Aslo note that there is another pair of signals in `django.contrib.auth.signals` please check if your IDE hasn't automatically imported from that one instead of `allauth.account.signals`.

Comment: Hi e4c4.  Thanks for your comments. Thanks to `User` instance, I can see who is the current user, the first time I see AnonymousUser which is ok, because up to this point, the user only have signed up, then, the next event is triggered (user_logged_in) and I can see here that the correct user is printer, the problem is after 2 events are fired, and I want to see a view with `@login_required()` decorator that I see that the user is actually not logged

Comment: Have you enabled the session middleware? Can you update your question with this new information and also with an extract from the sections of your settings file relevent to sessions etc.

Comment: @e4c5 i have the same problem, and the session middleware is activated, after redirection to accounts/profile user stays unauthenticated and i have no access to the django_allauth template tags